# css media queries not displaying

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

I have two stylesheets linked in the head like this...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 800px)" href="{% static '/mobile-style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 8000px)" href="/style.css">
```

and then in the sheets I have this:

style.css

```
body {color:blue;}
```

mobile-style.css

```
body {color:red}
```

But when I load the page I only ever see the style.css sheet and never the mobile-style.css sheet even if I load it in google Chrome's webmaster panel and toggle the device to something with a small screen. I have tries refreshing deleting cache, etc with no luck.

Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: Have you added the `viewport meta` tag?

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay I never came across any docs saying I had to add that, but I did add `<meta name="viewport" content="width">` before the stylesheets with no luck

Comment: It's maybe occurring because of "view port" add this     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

Comment: The second stylesheet applies to the same case as the first, because a max-width of 800px is also within the range of a max-width of 8000px. So your first one is being immediately overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here always apply css in `style.css` file. Because here you have put media query like below.

```
 @media(max-width: 800px){

  }
  @media(max-width: 8000px){

  }
```

Here `style.css` file media is `(max-width: 8000px)`. it's always true for `mobile-style.css` because it's media `(max-width: 800px)`. So always applya `style.css` file css style.

**Updated Answer...**
So, Try something like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 799px)" href="mobile-style.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 800px)" href="style.css">
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel dumb for missing that

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
 type="text/css"
  media="screen (max-width: 8000px)"
  href="/style.css">
```

and i have removed the AND and simply add media="screen (max-width:800px)" and it is working for me. thanks

Comment: why dd you start the sentence with and? and what?